# strftime localization timezone/display issue

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a datetime string that I want to localize to Chinese. I have a datetime string that looks like this: `2016-12-13 08:00:00` and I use `strftime` in the following way to set locale.

If I comment out the locale in my html the string is converted to a more verbose version in the correct local time zone that looks like this:

> Tue Dec 13 2016 03:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time).

However, when using locale it still shows a more verbose version, but the timezone is still in gmt like this:

> 2016年12月13日 星期二 08时00分00秒

with the time being 8 instead of 3 and no time zone shown. Does anyone know of some way to make it show in computer set local timezone after locale is changed?

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,'zh_CN.UTF-8');
echo strftime('%c', strtotime($appointment['appointment_datetime']));
$msg .='         <div id="appointment_datetime"><span>'.strftime("%B %d %Y %X", strtotime($appointment['appointment_datetime'])).'<span></div>';
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using javascript. Output just the y-m-d h:m:s string to html and then a jquery each function to turn the string into a datetime obj and use toLocaleTimeString to set locale and options.